# UNNotificationCategory and minimalActions in iOS10

Tags: notifications, ios10, xcode8, swift2

According to the documentation `UIUserNotificationActionContext` has been deprecated on iOS 10 and according to the deprecation message we should `Use UserNotifications Framework's -[UNNotificationCategory actions] or -[UNNotificationCategory minimalActions]`

The problem is that `minimalActions` does not exist as a property in `UNNotificationCategory`, according to both the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationcategory) and the header file (Funnily, a relevant page documenting `minimalActions` [exists](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationcategory/1649273-minimalactions#declarations) without being linked by anything else). So the question is, how does one set the minimal actions in iOS 10 beta 8? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `minimalActions` property of `UNNotificationCategory` existed in earlier betas, but I'm afraid it was removed in Xcode 8 beta 3, which explains why nothing links to that `minimalActions` page any more. Instead, set the regular `actions` property, and iOS will either show up to four or the first two depending on the context.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. Unfortunately, setting the `actions` property does not seem to have any effect under the `Minimal` context. The only action displayed is the default "Clear".